# Why does Express property ip not appear in Object.keys(request)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

consider the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    console.log(Object.keys(request));
    console.log(request.ip);
});
app.listen(1337);
```

In the first log we can see that `ip` is not a property of `request`, but in the second log `ip` is printed. Why does this happen?

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) return an array of the object **own enumerable** properties. So if the `ip` belongs somewhere in the prototype chain (not **owned**) or marked as a **non-enumerable** property, then it won't be listed.

Comment: .. same thing happens with arrays: `Object.keys(someArray);` won't contain the `length` property.

Comment: It appears to be marked as `enumerable: true` as well as set as an own property.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of Express

> [In this particular line](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L349)

Indicates that the **ip** index is not within the request object, express by default has that index as a function where it returns the values of **trust proxy fn** and returns it by passing it a **proxyaddr**.

```
Object.keys(Object) <- This only returns the indices that appear in the object.
```

So how are those dynamic and autogenerated indexes of Express **Object.keys(request)** not able to find it.

Comment: This for since the "ip" index is in the prototype of the request object

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of [this line](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L46). It is actually creating a new instance and using the `req` module as the prototype.

If you do this you'll see the IP property:

```
var express = require('express')
Object.keys(express.request)
```

The keys you're getting back is for the instance not all of the properties in the prototype chain. In fact its nested two levels deep:

```
var p1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(req)
var p2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(p1)
console.log(Object.keys(p1)) // ['app']
console.log(Object.keys(p2)) // [..., 'ip', ...]
```

Comment: Where can I lean more about prototypes and all that stuff?

Comment: Gustavo, in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys()` returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties (enumerable just means that if you tried to iterate through the object, only those properties whose enumerable property is set to `true` are looped on -- see `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`).

This could mean that the `ip` property is not owned by the `request` object  and that the `request` object is inheriting the `ip` property somewhere down the prototype chain.

To really prove that is the case, you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method.

First I simply tried `Object.getPrototypeOf(req)` but I did not find the `ip` property on the returned object. So I dug further down into the prototype chain.

`console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(req)));`

this returned an object with ip as a property

```
IncomingMessage {
  ...
  acceptsEncodings: [Function]
  ip: [Getter],
  ips: [Getter],
  ...
}
```

As stated earlier, because `ip` address property is inherited from the prototype chain, `Object.keys()` does not list `ip` as a property of the `req` object.

It also highlights another neat feature available in JS: Getters, aka computed property values.

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of
>   an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method
>   calls. Read about [Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on MDN.

That's exactly what's happening here. Express has some internal logic for picking out the IP address from the http request's payload and instead of having you access the IP address like so: `req.ip()`, Express developers have chosen to bind the `ip` property to a function that will get called when you access the `ip` property and you are simply able to access the IP address via `req.ip`.